# При наведении на элемент появляется дочерний элемент (главный элемент при этом увеличивается)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть код:

```css
.menu-new{float:right}
a.front-link
{
display: inline-block;  
background-color: #a73329; 
border-radius: 30px;
}
.front-img{
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
display: inline-block;
}
.menu-title{
color: #fff;  
display: none;  
}
a.front-link:hover .menu-title{  
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-new">
  <a class="front-link" href="#">
    <div class="front-img"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh5H3.png"  width="60" height="60" /></div>
    <div class="menu-title">О компании</div>
  </a>
  <a class="front-link" href="#">
    <div class="front-img"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh5H3.png"  width="60" height="60" /></div>
    <div class="menu-title">Продукция</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Задача такая: при наведении на `<a>` картинка должна плавно сдвигаться влево и там показывается `<div class="menu-title">`, следовательно, когда курсор убираешь с  `<a>` картинка плавно сдвигается вправо и пропадает `<div class="menu-title">`. Каким способом лучше реализовать с учетом правильного отображения в популярных браузерах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так:

```css
a.front-link,
.front-img {
  /*width: 120px;*/
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #a73329;
  display: inline-block;
  /* new */
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

a.front-link {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.front-img {
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 60px;
  background-position-x: right;
  /*left: 0%;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 1s;*/
}

.menu-title {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /* new */
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.front-img.__1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh5H3.png);
}

.front-img.__2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh5H3.png);
}

/* new */
a.front-link:hover {
  width: 180px;
}

/*a.front-link:hover .front-img {
  left: -100%;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="menu-new">
  <a class="front-link" href="#">
    <div class="menu-title">О компании</div>
    <div class="front-img __1"></div>
  </a>
  <a class="front-link" href="#">
    <div class="menu-title">Продукция</div>
    <div class="front-img __2"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**UPD**: обновил с плавающими элементами

Comment: Хороший вариант. Спасибо. Но нужно сделать типа: круглая иконка, а когда наводишь становить овал и справа появляется текст. А у вас в ответе ширина постоянно фиксирована.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов я сделал фиксированную ширину намеренно. Потому как при изменении размеров, у вас все что справа улетает.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Нужно что бы плавно показывалось

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов при таком подходе пользователю все время придется ловить элементы. Когда я пытаюсь с правого пункта сразу переместить мышь на левый, то кнопки начинают ползти вправо, т.к. уменьшается правый элемент. Элементы управления должны быть жестко привязаны к позиции, иначе это вызывает массу раздражений. Там либо кнопки надо делать с фиксированными размерами, либо по другому ставить вопрос - например все кнопки должны оставаться на месте, но элемент должен расширяться, при этом конечно элемент будет заползать сверху на соседние.

Comment: Ну... На вкус и цвет... По мне и так хорошо смотрится, просто хочется что бы плавно это все работало.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов я не про "цвет" и не про "красиво", я про удобство и юзабельность интерфейса. Попробуйте найти сайт, где элементы управления "плавают"

Comment: Я и взял пример с другого сайта.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов вот надо было оставить ссылку на тот самый сайт и спросить как можно повторить такой эффект, так было бы понятнее что там и как выглядит в реале. Вы же сами попробуйте переместить мышь с вашей правой кнопки на левую, вам бы такое понравилось, когда кнопка меню "убежала" из под вашей мышки.

Comment: Ссылки на stackoverflow не приветствуются, так же как и различного вида скрины. А что касается "переместить мышь с вашей правой кнопки на левую", да, на том сайте тоже самое.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов немного подправил

Comment: почитайте внимательнее вопрос